# Spring/Jboss - Current Request is not multipart request

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, jboss

I am trying to create a rest webservice in which the user sends httpPostrequest with some parameters . Here is my code

```
@RequestMapping(value="/SubmitDetails")
@ResponseBody
public String saveCase(@RequestParam("details") String details){
       //Do SomeWork
     return "some response";
}
```

But when I access this URL from my browser it throws :

```
exception

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: Current request is not a multipart request
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:982)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:690)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
    org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)

root cause

org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: Current request is not a multipart request
    org.springframework.web.method.annotation.RequestParamMethodArgumentResolver.handleMissingValue(RequestParamMethodArgumentResolver.java:188)
    org.springframework.web.method.annotation.AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.resolveArgument(AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.java:104)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:121)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:161)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:128)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:114)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:690)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
    org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
```

This code is working fine with Tomcat but not working with JBOSS 4.2

For Post Request I am using Volly from Android:

```
void HttpStringRequest(final int request , String url, final Map<String,String> keyVal){

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(request, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Helper.getmHelper().v(this.getClass().getName()+":RESPONSE:",response);

            hideProgress();
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Helper.getmHelper().v(this.getClass().getName()+":ERROR:","Error");

            hideProgress();
        }
    }
    ) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Iterator<Map.Entry<String, String>> it = keyVal.entrySet().iterator();
            while (it.hasNext()) {
                Map.Entry<String, String> pairs = (Map.Entry<String, String>) it.next();
                Helper.getmHelper().v(pairs.getKey(), pairs.getValue());
            }
            return keyVal;
        }

       @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
            headers.put("Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=utf-8");
            return headers;
        }


    };
    stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(60*1000,0,DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
    queue.add(stringRequest);
}
```

Comment: may you post also the code you use to make the post?

Comment: As I can see... you are using text/palin content type JBoss, instead, is waiting for a multipart; may you try to change the content type in multipart? So we can understand if is something related to the client side

Comment: How Jboss is waiting for the Multipart as I haven't declared anywhere . In my client code it i remove the header its still giving the same error. :(

Comment: You must not remove our header but put the header as multipart (this is strange i must admit)

Comment: added "multipart/form-data" same response from server. This all works fine in Tomcat server but not in JBoss

Comment: @AngeloImmediata Just tested, working fine in jboss-as-7.1.1.Final.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you have added CommonsMultipartResolver in Spring-Servlet.xml.

```
<bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver"/>
```

Then, add the enctype to multipart/form-data in your form:

```
<form id="fileupload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Finally in Controller, Request > MultipartHttpServletRequest:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/SubmitDetails"  method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String saveCase(MultipartHttpServletRequest request) {}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying, I am not expecting multipart data in my api. I tried the same code in Jboss 7.1 AS , and its working find there . I think the problem is related to the Jboss 4.2.